# Does std Class in PHP creates a Hidden Fields for each property

Tags: php

```
$Var = new StdClass;

if($_POST['somvar']){
$Var->somvar = $_POST['somvar']
}
else
{
 $somevar=''
}
```

Why is it creating hidden varaible  for  this statement
"$Var->somvar = $_POST['somvar']" 
when i  see the view source

How do i persist the state of this variable when moving to next pages

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your question at all.

Comment: I don't know what wrong with those line ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your second question is probably [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

```
session_start();

$Var = new StdClass;

if($_POST['somvar']){
$Var->somvar = $_POST['somvar']
}

// Objects need to be serialized to be stored in $_SESSION
$_SESSION["Var"] = serialize ($Var);
```

to access $Var on another page:

```
session_start();

if (array_key_exists("Var", $_SESSION))
 $Var = unserialize($_SESSION["Var"]);

if (!empty($Var->somvar))
 echo "Somvar is: ".$Var->somvar;
```

Comment: @stereofrog true. I felt it okay in this case, seeing as it's a combination of questions. Still, editing.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to serialize objects to put them into sessions. It's just a matter of making the definitions available upon session_start or use an autoloader.